# PIC:How to enable watch dog timer in PIC18F67K22 controller?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, watchdog

- I am using PIC18F67K22 controller in my circuit.
- I don't know how to enable or configure **Watch Dog Timers(WDT)** in my controller.
- Any one have explanation with some demo code of Enable Watch Dog Timer ???

regards,

shailesh

Comment: Pages 419-420 of the [PIC18F67K22 datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39960d.pdf) seem pretty clear. What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: Here you have a step-by-step on what it is and how to set it up: http://www.gooligum.com.au/tutorials/baseline/PIC_Base_A_7.pdf

Comment: -1 for clearly not even looking at the datasheet.

Comment: This question doesn't belong here since it is answered clearly and directly in the datasheet.  We are not here to read the datasheet for you.

Comment: insufficient preliminary research

Comment: This isn't obvious to a newcomer: control registers can be confusing, and the WDT can be particularly intimidating to new comers (I always left it off until I was more comfortable with the feature).  There are two ways of setting it: 1. you can set it in code at initialization, or 2. MPLab has a "Configure" menu, select this, then select "Configuration Bits...", and here you can setup the crystal, WDT and other device specific configurations.  Be careful with your configuration initialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the 0th bit in WDTCON register

`WDTCON.0 = 1`

The rest of the bits in WDTCON let you configure this peripheral, see datasheet for more brief notes. In this context, datasheets and microcontroller-header are your best-friends.

[image]

Note: **Before** you enable SWDTEN, You will have to make sure WDTEN is disabled, else you wouldn't be able to enable Watchdog Timer via SWDTEN. This can be done by clearing WDTEN bits in CONFIG2H Register.

Comment: You mean init of WDT is only set this bit??? How to use this two function "char isWDTTO(void)"  and "char isWDTWU(void)"??

Comment: Yes. That sounds like a new question where you'd want to submit its code. Based on a small search, it's a method to detect if reset is required.